# Excel VBA - Copying non-adjacent range to a different non-adjacent range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to run through a loop of data  and copy across certain cells from one sheet to another. Using "longhand" I can get the following to work :

```
Sub Update()
Dim Template As Worksheet: Set Template = Worksheets("ImportTemplate")
Dim Master As Worksheet: Set Master = Worksheets("Master")
Dim a As Long, x As Long

With Master
For a = 2 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case .Range("A" & a).Value
        Case "S"
            x = Template.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Template.Range("A" & x).Value = .Range("E" & a).Value 'Site Details
            Template.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("AO" & a).Value 'Meter Details
        Case "M"

        Case "C"

        Case Else
    End Select
Next a
.Select
End With
End Sub
```

Is there any "better" way of doing this ? There will be far more cells to update so it's not limited to the 2 shown for example

Comment: If there are a lot of cells, I'd probably work with VBA arrays rather than going back and forth to the worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

You could include

```
' at the start
Dim priorCalculationSetting as Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
priorCalc = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

...your code here...

' at the end
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = priorCalculationSetting
```